# Displaying a tooltip for each Combobox item when the list is opened C# WPF XAML MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, combobox, tooltip

I'm developing an application in C# MVVM
My question is about adding a tooltip for each item that the ComboBox is binded to. Since there are two items only I want it to show the tooltip whenever I open the dropdown and hover my mouse over one of the items , like this:

if I hover my mouse over the first element in the dropDown I'll get a ToolTip with " first item".. and "second item" when I hover over the second element.

ComboBox is placed in DataGridTemplateColumn -> Cell Template -> DataTemplate

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn Header="PRĄD POJEMNOŚCIOWY [A]" HeaderStyle="{StaticResource PRAD_POJEMNOSCIOWY}">
 <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
  <DataTemplate>
   <ComboBox Name="PradPojemnosciowyComboBox"
             SelectedValue="{Binding SelectedItem, Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
             ItemsSource="{Binding Path=LiniaWyComboBox, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
             IsEditable="True"
             IsReadOnly="False"
             Text="{Binding Prad_pojemnosciowy, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
             IsTextSearchEnabled="False" 
             IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"
             PreviewKeyDown="PradPojemnosciowyComboBox_OnPreviewKeyDown">

          <ComboBox.Style>
           <Style TargetType="ComboBox">
            <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="SelectedValue" Value="{x:Null}">
          <Setter Property="SelectedIndex" Value="{Binding LiniaWyComboBox}"/>
            </Trigger>
           </Style.Triggers>
          </Style>
    </ComboBox.Style>
   </ComboBox>
  </DataTemplate>
 </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

**UPDATE**

ToolTipLabel.cs:

```
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;

namespace GPZmodel.UserControlsGraphicGenerators
{
   public class ToolTipLabel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string _toolTipText;
    public string ToolTipText
    {
        get { return _toolTipText;}
        set
        {
            if (_toolTipText != value)
            {
                _toolTipText = value;
            }
        }
    }
    public ObservableCollection<ToolTipLabel> ToolTipList = new ObservableCollection<ToolTipLabel>()
    {
        new ToolTipLabel() {ToolTipText = "Nazwa1"} ,
        new ToolTipLabel() {ToolTipText = "Nazwa2"} ,

    };

    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}
```

}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use an `ItemContainerStyle`:

```
<ComboBox Name="PradPojemnosciowyComboBox"
             SelectedValue="{Binding SelectedItem, Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
             ItemsSource="{Binding Path=LiniaWyComboBox, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
             IsEditable="True"
             IsReadOnly="False"
             Text="{Binding Prad_pojemnosciowy, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
             IsTextSearchEnabled="False" 
             IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"
             PreviewKeyDown="PradPojemnosciowyComboBox_OnPreviewKeyDown">
    <ComboBox.Style>
        <Style TargetType="ComboBox">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="SelectedValue" Value="{x:Null}">
                    <Setter Property="SelectedIndex" Value="{Binding LiniaWyComboBox}"/>
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </ComboBox.Style>
    <ComboBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ComboBoxItem">
            <Setter Property="ToolTip">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" />
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </ComboBox.ItemContainerStyle>
</ComboBox>
```

Bind the `TextBlock` in the `ToolTip` to whatever property of your data object that you want to display.

Comment: Hi! It does show a small "box" when I move mouse over the items but my ComboBox style changes to.. worse-looking. It doesn't bind from my ToolTipLabel also. See update.

I know I should add some logic, but is something like 
if(ComboBoxItem.index == 0)
ToolTipText = ToolTipList[0];
else
{...}

Comment: Is your `DataGrid` bound to `ToolTipList`? Or what is LiniaWyComboBox?

Comment: No it is not. It is bound to LiniaWyComboBox property of the class LineOut which is an ObservableCollection<double>. "LineWy" = "LineOut"

Comment: So what do you want to display in the tooltip if you are displaying double values in the DataGrid?

Comment: I want someone to know what those two values in the combobox mean, just an information about those values. What you mean is that when DataGrid is bound to doubles Combobox won't update anything else? Like I explained? Thanks for helping me out :)

Comment: You didn't answer my question. What exactly do you want to display in the ComboBox. Just bind the TextBlock to this property.

Comment: Well.. DataGrid has this : ItemsSource="{Binding LiniaWyComboBox, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Window}, Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}". I bind the TextBlock to ToolTipText from ToolTipLabel.cs and it never goes there eventually

Comment: How is it supposed to find the ToolTipText  property? Where and how are you instantiating the ToolTipLabel?

Comment: <TextBlock Text="{Binding ToolTipText}" /> I've provided code for ToolTipLabel.cs in the Update of my post

Comment: But where do you instantiate the type...? You have posted a class definition but it's unclear how you use it.

Comment: public ToolTipLabel TT { get; set; } = new ToolTipLabel(); I have this line in ViewModel and actually I don't know what to do next. Maybe I don't instantiate it properly.. I did TT.ToolTipNext = "TextToBeShown" in the PradPojemnosciowyComboBox_OnDropDownOpened method. Still no result

Comment: How to bind to a particular property is not really related to your original question about how to display a tooltip for each item.

Comment: I've got this error :  System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error: 'ToolTipText' property not found on 'object' ''Double' (HashCode=1076756480)'. BindingExpression:Path=ToolTipText; DataItem='Double' (HashCode=1076756480); target element is 'TextBlock' (Name=''); target property is 'Text' (type 'String')